# How do I delete an accidental Loop Cut?

Tags: geometry

I have accidentally inserted an edge loop using "Loop Cut".

To remove it, I click an Edge, then I choose Select Loops -> Edge Loops.

Then I press Del on the keyboard, then Delete Edges.

This removes something else.
What am I doing, and how could I delete just the accidental edge loop?

[image: blender screenshot]

[image]

Comment: Select the whole loop you want deleted (loop select, alt RMB on loop for me) then delete (x) -> edge loops.

Comment: @Nathan It doesn't work for my blend file. It leaves some artifact edges, and I don't see why.

Comment: If it's not a continuous loop, it will turn borders into triangles in preference to turning them into ngons.

Comment: @Nathan I am pretty sure that before my accidental loop, the "hole" was without the 2 edges.

Comment: Deleting edges operator was never expected to leave faces in place, it deletes edges and faces if those deleted edges were holding faces. X > Dissolve works just fine, in this case as well. Edges left are not "artifact" edges rather edges necessary to support the indent in the center since Blender doesn't support Ngons with holes without any edges holding those holes

Answer (score 5):

Select the loop cut, press <kbd>X</kbd> , and select *Dissolve Edges*.

Comment: This doesn't really work. It leaves some artifacts. You can see that when you try my blend file.

Answer (score 3):

You can press <kbd>2</kbd> on the keyboard and press <kbd>Cmd</kbd> and <kbd>x</kbd> (or <kbd>X</kbd> and dissolve edges).

These artifacts that you get are necessary for the hole, so that Blender knows that there is a hole there.

Comment: @user92758 I am pretty sure that before my accidental edge loop, the hole was there without any edges around it.

Comment: Then you have to do 2 times a edge (ctrl and j) between a Vertices of the hole and a Vertices not on the hole